# How would one force VSCode Omnisharp not to use MONO?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, mono

OS: Linux Manjaro

VSCODE: Code-oss 1.47.1-1
c# Extension: ver 1.22.1
Issue: When opening C# programs, VSCode Screams dozens of errors both in the code and some config file.
Potential cause: This only happens when I have Mono and MSBUIL-MONO installed. When I uninstall them, the issue seems to disappear. This is further confirmed with the Omnisharp Logs.

Omnisharp log with MONO installed.

```
OmniSharp server started with Mono 6.8.0.
Path: /home/paul/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.1/.omnisharp/1.35.3/omnisharp/OmniSharp.exe
PID: 9916
```

Omnisharp log without MONO installed.

```
OmniSharp server started.
Path: /home/paul/.vscode-oss/extensions/ms-dotnettools.csharp-1.22.1/.omnisharp/1.35.3/run
PID: 1500
```

This issue is resolved when I uninstall MONO but having to constantly uninstall and reinstall MONO isn't a solution, is it.

Question: How would I start the Omnisharp so that it doesn't start with MONO? Which config files would I have to edit and how?
The project I've been doing is the simple "Hello World" program that is automatically generated when making a new console application.(by typing dotnet new console in the terminal).
Any help with this would be great.
thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues You might talk to its developers or dig into the code base.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was an issue with a path change in mono and they needed to patch OmniSharp to update.

https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases/tag/v1.23.11

The resolution is to set the plugin that requires it (VSCode) to not use the global instance and use one per project instead...

Preferences > Settings > Extensions > C# configuration > Omnisharp: Use Global Mono > Never

[image]

Comment: I have the latest VSC, mono installed (and in PATH), latest version of C# extension, and this "Use global mono" does not exist on my installation.

Comment: @jhc Seems like it was removed, see: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5228#issuecomment-1137502533

Answer (score 0):

That has worked for me:

In VS Code, go to File > Preferences > Settings > Extensions > C# Configuration > Change "Omnisharp: Use Global Mono" (you can search for it if the menu is too long) to "Never"